# how to make a column not to display 0 as decimal but should display decimals other then zero

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sqldatatypes

consider a column which contains both decimal and non decimal number

```
 col1 
    98
    99.0
    66.2 
    99.6
    76
```

Expected after cast function

```
 col1 
    98
    99
    66.2 
    99.6
    76
```

I tried to do it as

```
select cast(col1 as decimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_replace(col1,'\\.0+$','')` --matches . literally and any number of zeroes at the end of the string.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select  
stack(5,'98',
        '99.0',
        '66.2',
        '99.6',
        '76') as col1 
)

select regexp_replace(col1,'\\.0+$','') as col1 from mytable;
```

Result:

```
col1
98
99
66.2
99.6
76
```

But it will leave values like `66.20` as is. If you want to remove also non-significant trailing zeroes: `66.20` --> `66.2` and `66.60200` --> `66.602`, `66.0` --> `66` and leave `600` as is then use this:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'\\.0+$',''),'(\\d+\\.\\d+?)0+$','$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case when` to do this. The resulting column will be of string type though because of the display format that you prefer.

```sql
select 
    case when round(col1, 0) = col1 
         then cast(cast(round(col1, 0) as int) as string)
         else cast(col1 as string)
    end
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried float data type ?

```
select cast(99.0 as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to a string, if you want to control the formatting.  This would often be done in the application level.
But you can do it in the database as well:

```
select replace(printf(col1, '%.1f', col1), '.0', '')
```

This formats the string using two decimal places.  It then removes `'.0'` if present.